# Itext7 - Auto resize image

Tags: java, html, pdf, itext7

I use iText (Version 7.1.1) to convert html to pdf using HtmlConverter (html2pdf version 2.0.1) :

```
public static ByteArrayOutputStream htmlToPDFStream(String htmlBody)
        throws DocumentException, IOException {
ConverterProperties props = new ConverterProperties();

FontProvider fp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, false, false);
for (String font : FONTS) {
    FontProgram fontProgram = FontProgramFactory.createFont(font);
    fp.addFont(fontProgram);
}

props.setFontProvider(fp);

com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter writer = new com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfWriter(outputStream);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
Document document = new Document(pdf);

List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new ByteArrayInputStream(htmlBody.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)), props);
for (IElement element : elements) {
    document.add((IBlockElement)element);
}
document.close();
return  outputStream;
}
```

It works good if the HTML string has small images (smaller than default page size A4).
But if I have an image bigger than default page width, the result will be cropped image in pdf.

**Is there any way to tell iText to make auto resizing if the image is bigger than default pdf page size to be fit?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images in layout have autoscale property which should result in desired behavior. You would need to define a custom `ITagWorker` to actually add this property to the produced image elements.

You would also have to define a custom `ITagWorkerFactory` to use new `ITagWorker` for images.

The code is very simple, you just have to tie everything together carefully:

```
class CustomImageWorker extends ImgTagWorker {
    public CustomImageWorker(IElementNode element, ProcessorContext context) {
        super(element, context);
    }

    @Override
    public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
        return ((Image)super.getElementResult()).setAutoScale(true);
    }
}

ITagWorkerFactory customFactory = new DefaultTagWorkerFactory() {
    @Override
    public ITagWorker getCustomTagWorker(IElementNode tag, ProcessorContext context) {
        if (TagConstants.IMG.equals(tag.name())) {
            return new CustomImageWorker(tag, context);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
};
```

After that, just set your tag factory to the props: `props.setTagWorkerFactory(customFactory);`

Another solution at the CSS level would be to specify different image widths and heights depending on the media device settings, such as device width and height. See `@media` CSS rule documentation.

**UPD** If you don't have any `width` or `height` CSS properties defined for images, you can compare their sizes to page sizes directly, but keep in mind px to pt conversion rate. Example:

```
@Override
public IPropertyContainer getElementResult() {
    Image result = ((Image)super.getElementResult());
    if (!processed) {
        float imageWidth = result.getImageScaledWidth();
        float pageMargin = 36 * 2;
        float maxWidth = PageSize.A4.getWidth() - pageMargin;
        float maxHeight = PageSize.A4.getHeight() - pageMargin;
        if (imageWidth * 0.75 > maxWidth) {
            result.scaleToFit(maxWidth / 0.75f, maxHeight / 0.75f);
        }
        processed = true;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: @ Alexey Subach : Thank you for your suggestion, it is a good idea but in this case all images will be resized.
I meant not only the very large image will be resized but also the small one => the small image resolution will be some times very bad.
can we add in "if" structure new condition to make the resizing just for those images which have size larger than default page size.
I can't find such that attribute in (img) tag that gives me image size to compare it with (com.itextpdf.kernel.geom.PageSize.A4).

Comment: @ Alexey Subach : Thank you again for your response. but I don't understand why should I test if it is "processed" and how?

Comment: @MuatazKanjo `getElementResult()` can be called several times. `processed` is just a flag (an internal field in your custom class) that makes sure you don't execute the code that mutates the state of the class twice.

Comment: Thank you very much, your suggestion solves my problem.